# How can I increase a counter on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a counter that increases on button click.  I tried the following code, but the value printed stays the same:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gonder").click(function() {
        var baslik = document.title;
        var sayi = 1;
        var sayi1 = sayi++;

        document.title = '(' +sayi+ ')' + baslik;
    });
});
```

What how can I do my want?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question, but I couldn't bring myself to edit the last line.  I thought it sounded too good the way it is now.

Comment: thank u , i have been learned English for 4 months and sometimes i write wrong :)

Comment: your question was very understandable.  For only 4 months of learning, you're doing very well.  Keep up the good work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your counter outside of the function. You were clearing it on every click.

```
var sayi = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gonder").click(function() {
    var baslik = document.title;
    sayi++;
     document.title = '(' +sayi+ ')' + baslik;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest i can think of

```
<button>clicked 0 times</button> 
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
     count++;
    $(this).text("clicked "+count+" times");
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/PKcrd/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly detailed writup I did on closures using your exact goal as the straw man (er... problem)

http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/09/javascript-event-handler-persistance-with-closures

Basically you can do it one of 2 ways.

- create a counter variable outside the scope of the event handler.

  ```
  var count = 0;
  element.onclick = function() {
      count++;
  };
  ```
- use a closure to provide each element its own unique counter contained within the event handler itself. Which I detail in my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gonder").click(function() {
    var baslik = document.title;
    var sayi = 1;
    clickCounter++;

    document.title = '(' +sayi+ ')' + baslik;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
var sayi = 1;
var baslik = document.title;
$("#gonder").click(function() {
    document.title = '(' + (++sayi) + ')' + baslik;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
<button class="counter">I have been clicked 0 times</button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    $('button.counter').click(function(){
        count++;
        $(this).text("clicked "+count+" times");
    });
</script>
```

That is the simplest I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn" onclick="f1();">Button</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var count=0;
function f1()
{

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=count;
    count++;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations about your answer? Thank you